# How to select each individual character in Python?

Tags: python

So I want the user to input a word and in a separate text file it will have something like a = z which means I want it to look at each character in their word and if there's an "a" it will be replaced with a "z".  How can I select each character in Python and replace letters/numbers etc in a word?

Comment: why use a text file when you can use a dictionary?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.  There are many other good online Python tutorial resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume your file is a simple text file, with on each line, a letter, an equal sign, and then another letter to replace the first with.

```
a=b
c=f
...
```

First, read the file, and construct a dictionary mapping the old values to the new ones:

```
d = None
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    d = {}
    for line in lines:
        old, new = l.split('=')
        d[old] = new

   # the last 5 lines accomplish the same thing as this
   # d = {l.split('=')[0] : l.split('=')[1] for l in lines]
```

Then iterate through that dictionary and preform the replacements.

```
s = 'my cool string'
for old, new in d.items()
    s = s.replace(old, new)
```

Comment: I'm still fairly new to Python so I'm a little confused.  Can you explain the code for me?  I don't understand "as f" or the "d =...." part also, this code will check each character and replace it with the ones I set in my text file?

Comment: See my edit. Basically `d = {l.split('=')[0] : l.split('=')[1] for l in lines]` is a shorthand for creating dictionaries in python. I've replaced it in the code above with an identical albeit longer statement. As for the part with the `open` statement, that's how you read text files in python. If you're still new to that, I reccomend this [official tutorial to reading files](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Still lost :/.  I can't find anything that will fully explain that line of code.  Also, for s = 'my cool string'
for old, new in d.items()
    s = s.replace(old, new)  I don't understand the d.items() part.  I understand you have s = "my cool strin" and s = s.replace(old, new) will replace the older character with the new.

Comment: At this point I recommend you read a good intro to python tutorial or book. Perhaps [the Beginner's guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) ? The line of code with `open` is detailed in the link above,  The second part (s = ... ) shows how to take your input string (s) and the apply all the replacement rules that you have just read from your text file.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to give this a full read over because I feel like I should understand exactly what this code is doing haha.  If you have any other recommended guides I would appreciate the link:).  Thank you

Comment: take a look at https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonBooks :) and feel free to accept the answer if it has answered your question!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.replace('a', 'z')` you don't need to loop though each char in the string. .replace essentially does that for you.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20replace#str.replace

```
str.replace(old, new[, max])
```

Comment: If you're going provide a link, at least link the doc :) https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20replace#str.replace